# Why creating table type and stored procedure using that time simultaneously dont work

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am trying to run this script. There is more to it i am using this for unit testing these stored procedures:

```
--StudentType   
    CREATE TYPE Student AS TABLE
    (
        Id varchar(19) NOT NULL primary key, 
        Count int NOT NULL
    );
    GO

    --Class
    CREATE PROCEDURE #Class_Data        
        @SList AS Student READONLY, 
        @RNumber VARCHAR(50)    

    AS
    BEGIN       
        INSERT INTO Class(ClassNumber, Count, RollNumber)
                SELECT
                    Id, Count, @RNumber From @SList 
    END


    GO
```

Script works if i run Type first and than run the Stored Procedure. But why dont it run if i run them together? Can someone please tell if there is a way to run this?

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`#` designates a temporary stored procedure. It seems that this is an old feature which wasn't update in SQL2008 (table parameters are a new feature in SQL2008) to permit table parameters. For SQL2000 (!) [Books Online](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa174792%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) says:

"*SQL Server 2000 also supports temporary stored procedures [...]. **Temporary stored procedures** are stored in tempdb and **are useful** when connected **to earlier versions** (SQL7, 6.5 ?!) of SQL Server.*"

I would say that temporary stored procedures are an old feature in SQL2000 and not to mention in SQL2008.

But, if you try to create a non-temp. SP then `CREATE PROCEDURE Class_Data` will be executed successfully.

Also, you should avoid `@var AS type` syntax because within SQL `AS` keyword is used for designating an alias (ex. `SELECT Column1 AS Col1` or `FROM table1 AS t1`) or for computed columns `Column1 AS (expression) [PERSISTED]`.

Comment: What you mean by avoid us of var AS?? Should i just say Declare var name?? no AS?

Comment: `CREATE PROCEDURE Class_Data        
        @SList /*AS*/ Student READONLY ...`